# Content Assist Eclipse C - Show Pr

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've a problem with Eclipse and its content assist. I've already checked that the content assist is enabled but when i pressed the combination assigned to it, eclipse show me only the string 'Pr'. 
Where am i wrong?
Here it's a pic.

[image: Content Assist]

As request from `justinmreina` here's another example of the same error.
I want to choose from the content assist window the atoi function, but i get instead the same 'Pr' message. If i hit return i'd get atof().

[image]

Comment: What language is this? Content assist is very dependent on the programming language.

Comment: can you please post a larger chunk of the code so I can understand the scope of your variable? i.e. the whole function if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There a few things to resolve before debugging further. What you are seeing is strange for me, given what I know.

1. Which perspective are you in when performing the editing (C/C++?)

   [image]
2. Which Proposal set does Pr show up for?

   [image]
3. Which OS & Eclipse Version are you using?

   - how long ago did you install it? What are the main plugins you've installed?

   .
4. Which Proposals are you setup to use?

   You can find these under **Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced**. You're mysterious '**Pr**' must be coming from one of these.

   [image]

answering these four questions should certainly hone in on the problem. If this isn't a configuration problem on your side, then perhaps your eclipse install is corrupted, or its a bug!

**Misc Question**

The assignment for *sql* is (I think) not valid syntax. Is this your shorthand for:

```
sprintf(sql, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS e FROM peer p WHERE p.user=%s;", user);
```

strangely this compiles and runs, but I don't know why!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char mysql_str[] = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS e FROM peer p WHERE p.user=%s;", user;

    printf(mysql_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Marco, do you know why it compiles, and prints output to console? for me it prints:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS e FROM peer p WHERE p.user=�����;
```

maybe I am missing something on C strings and syntax... note that in the example code above user is never declared.

Comment: 1 - The selected perspective is C/C++
2 - I have no Proposal set at all, I only have 'Pr' when i hit Ctrl+Space
3 - I'm running Eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64 on Opensuse 13.1. The plugin i've installed is Dbeaver
4 - I've set the proposal as your example but i didn't see any improvement.
Misc Question: Yes, i know i'm wrong at the string assignment, i've already correct that line.

Comment: cool; thx for this info. Just for fun, if you uninstall Dbeaver 4 does the problem go away? Also, try downloading a clean Eclipse-SDK download, open it up, import the project and see if the problem persists.

Comment: where did you get your eclipse version (Eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64). I can't seem to find where one downloads that (not listed on Eclipse-Distro page (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)

Comment: Here it is the link http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz